# Find Substring from XML Tag using Shell Script

Tags: arrays, xml, shell, awk, sed

I have an XML file of the format:

```
<classes>

 <subject lb="Fall Sem 2020">
  <name>Operating System</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Theory</type>
  <faculty>Prof. XYZ</faculty> 
 </subject>

 <subject lb="Spring Sem 2020">
  <name>Web Development</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Lab</type>
 </subject>

 <subject lb="Fall Sem 2021">
  <name>Computer Network</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Theory</type>
  <faculty>Prof. ABC</faculty> 
 </subject>

 <subject lb="Spring Sem 2021">
  <name>Software Engineering</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Lab</type>
 </subject>

</classes>
```

Expected Output:

```
Fall Sem 2020
Spring Sem 2020
Fall Sem 2021
Spring Sem 2021
```

I want to extract the values of `lb` in an array.

My try: I tried using `sed -n "/lb="/,\/"/p" file.xml` but this command is not giving me the values present for the particular label.

What could be the correct way to deal with this problem?

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: I know xmlstarlet is good to play with all xml related operation but currently I have some restrictions. That's why I'm using ```sed``` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting an attribute value in xml element.

If no XML parser is available. With GNU sed:

```
sed -En 's/.* lb="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file
```

Output:

```
Fall Sem 2020
Spring Sem 2020
Fall Sem 2021
Spring Sem 2021
```

Comment: Also, I need some good tutorials on dealing with the regular expression that we give in our command. Will you recommend me some blogs/tutorials?

Comment: [This](https://riptutorial.com/sed/example/8893/backreference) might help with the backreference (`\1`) I used and [this](http://www.skybert.net/unix/non-greedy-matching-in-sed/) with non-greedy matching (`[^"]+`).

Comment: Is there any way I can get this resultant in an array? I tried using ```arr=($(sed -En 's/.* lb="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file))``` but this is giving me me individual word as an array element.

Comment: I suggest to start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following in `awk` considering that you don't have any way to use xml tools.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
/<subject lb="/{
  match($0,/".*"/)
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}
' Input_file
```